# How to swap two cell ranges after applying filter VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

[![Rows to swap][1]][1]I am working on a code that applies a filter (criteria is taken from another file, and that works fine), and then it has to swap the data of the two filtered rows. However, I am facing error as it selects the unfiltered data range in third row even though I apply the Visible cell type function.

So basically after the filter is applied, I want to swap the data between B76 and B82 and G76:AP76 and G82:AP82
`

```
Windows("complete Availability 22-3-2021").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$EL$1561").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        po1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=pi1
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Set r1 = Range("B2,G2:AP2").Offset(Rowoffset:=1, Columnoffset:=0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
tmp1 = r1
Set r2 = Range("B2,G2:AP2").Offset(Rowoffset:=2, Columnoffset:=0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

tmp2 = r2
r1 = tmp2
r2 = tmp1

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd loop within the range finding some key value to do that... you can't just `Offset` from row 2 to the next visible row like that.

Comment: Also you can't use the Value property of a discontinuous range to get an array which you can then assign to a different range.

Comment: What do you expect from the range r1 to return? It will return an error if criteria are not matched on the respective rows. It literally tries setting the cells on row 3 (or 4), even **if they are hidden**, returning an error in such a case. Do you want setting **the second and the third row of the filtered range**, in fact? And pictures of your initial and final situation may help us better understand what you need...

Comment: Could you share two screenshots (before and after) with row and column headings? You can edit your question at any time. A typical swap is done in three steps, e.g. `t = r1, r1 = r2, r2 = t`, How do you want to swap? If the resulting rows are e.g. `2, 4, 7, 9, 12`, then if you swap each next with each previous you'll end up with this resulting order: `4, 7, 9, 12, 2`. On the other hand, if you want to swap only row pairs, you'll get `4, 2, 9, 7, 12`. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not answer my clarification questions, but I cannot stop myself thinking that you need swapping the mentioned ranges in the **filtered range**. If so, please try the next code:

```
Sub testSwapColumnsVC()
 Dim rngF As Range, po1 As String, pi1 As String, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
 Dim arrtemp, firstC As String, lastC As String, cel As Range
 Dim arrHidCol, colN As Long, i As Long, k As Long, sh As Worksheet, boolOptimized As Boolean
 
   boolOptimized = True 'change it in False when debugging!
   
   If boolOptimized Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.EnableEvents = False
   End If
 
  Set sh = ActiveSheet     'use here your sheet by its name
  
  po1 = "AA": pi1 = "BB" 'use here your criteria (I used these only for testing reason)
  
    sh.AutoFilterMode = False 'no need to manually eliminate the filter

    sh.Range("$A$2:$EL$1561").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                                    po1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=pi1
                                         
    'Unhide the hidden columns, and memorize them in an array:__
    colN = sh.UsedRange.Columns.count
    ReDim arrHidCol(colN)
    For i = 1 To colN
        If sh.cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden Then
            sh.cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            arrHidCol(k) = i: k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arrHidCol(k - 1) 'keep only the array elements having values
    '__________________________________________________
    
    Set rngF = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$EL$1561").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'the filtered Total range
    
    Set r1 = setRangeByRow(rngF, 2)  'create the range of the second filtered/visible cells row
    Set r2 = setRangeByRow(rngF, 3)  'create the range of the third filtered/visible cells row
    
    firstC = r1.cells(1).Address(0, 0)        'r1 Range first cell address
    lastC = Split(r1.Address(0, 0), ":")(1) 'r1 Range last cell address

  arrtemp = Range(firstC & ":" & lastC).value 'keep an unchanged reference of r1 (but continuous range!)
  For Each cel In r1.cells                             'use the r1  cells as column reference!
      cel.value = r2.cells(1, cel.Column - (r1.Column - 1)).value 'swap the cells value placing r2 ones in r1
      'use the temp array to swap in r2 cells:
      r2.cells(1, cel.Column - (r1.Column - 1)).value = arrtemp(1, cel.Column - (r1.Column - 1))
 Next cel
 
 'Hide the previous hidden columns_______
 For i = 0 To UBound(arrHidCol)
    sh.Columns(arrHidCol(i)).Hidden = True
 Next
 '__________________________________
 
 'Remove optimization:
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function setRangeByRow(rng As Range, iRow As Long) As Range 'create the range for a specific filtered area row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, A As Range
    For Each A In rng.Areas
        For j = 1 To A.rows.count
            i = i + 1
            If i = iRow Then
                Set setRangeByRow = Intersect(A.rows(j), rng.Parent.Range("B:B,G:AP"))
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next
End Function
```

**Edited**:

I adapted the code to work in case of hidden columns, too. Excel is not able to create an acurate intersection between discontinuous ranges...

Now, i firstly unhide the hidden columns, memorize them in an array and re hide them at the end.

Besides that, it has some optimization setting, in order to make the code faster.

Please, send some feedback after testing it...

Comment: Hey so first off, THANK You for this
Secondly I tried running it but it gave Object variable not Set error at cel.value=r2.cells(1,cel.Column.....

Comment: I am driving now... I will answer whwn I will be at home. After some hours.

Comment: @Roha Ashfaq: So, let us debug it... Firstly, if not something confidential in your workbook, if you share it, I will explain what goes wrong. If not possible to share it, let us look to the error message and deduce what could be wrong. Firstly, I suppose that you used your real criteria... Let us see if `r2` range has been set. Place the next code line `Debug.Print r2 is Nothing` after `Set r2 = setRangeByRow(rngF, 3)`. Does it return `True` in Immediate Window? If yes, the `r2` range has not been set. Can you see if the used criteria filters in a way to be less then three visible rows?

Comment: Hey so I placed the line and it returned True in Immediate Window. How to set 'r2' range?

Comment: It is not possible to share the file. Moreover, can you explain what you mean by the last line?

Comment: @Roha Ashfaq: Do you use the code like it is? If you tried implementing it in your code, are the code line `Set r2 = setRangeByRow(rngF, 3)` present in the code you use. Maybe it will be good to edit your question and post the actual code you use. In the last line of my previous comment I suggested you to check if applying your filter criteria the resulted filtered range does not have less then three rows...

Comment: I used your code as it is, and I also used Set r2=setRangeByRow(rngF,3)
The filter criteria always returns two rows of data below header row
I will edit the question to post the recent image

Comment: @Roha Ashfaq: Then, put a break point on the line `Set r2 = setRangeByRow(rngF, 3)` and then run the function code line by line  (pressing F8)  observing what wrong is happening. There the necessary range should be returned... If you cannot share the workbook, do you use AnyDesk application? If yes, I have few minutes now and I could examine the problem remotely... It is difficult to understand what happens, since it worked well on my test worksheet. It is only obvious that `r2` has not been created by the function. Why that, difficult to imagine without seeing what's happening...

Comment: Can I share the file via chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231642/discussion-between-roha-ashfaq-and-faneduru).

Comment: @Roha Ashfaq: I do not know if it is possible to share a file via chat. I will access the link to the chat room.

Comment: Lets connect on AnyDesk

Comment: @Roha Ashfaq: I am trying to connect but AnyDesk is not started on your computer...

Comment: can you come in discussion?

Comment: @Roha Ashfaq: What kind of discussion? In the meantime I played a little with the code and adapted the function to work with hidden rows, too. Not necessarily to previously unhide columns and hide them at the end. The above version could be inconvenient if some errors exists in the cells to be swapped and code stops. I was to lazy to adapt the above solution.

Comment: That's wonderful, I have another question that I shared in discussion chat with you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412097/do-while-loop-on-visible-cells-only-after-autofilter/67412389#67412389

would love if you could help!