# Do while loop on visible cells only after autofilter?

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck on a code where I apply a filter and then have to copy paste data from filtered rows to another sheet. But for some reason the code is not doing anything at all. I have applied an if condition but that is not working, it would be better if the condition was visible cells condition. Basically I want to apply filter>> then I want to copy cell in column 2 to another worksheet and perform calculation>> then copy calculated value in cell in column 7

```
Sub DOCFairshare()
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final Orders") 'Setting worksheet in variable
ws.Activate
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False   'Removing all filters
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$EL$1561").AutoFilter Field:=50, Criteria1:= _
        "DOC Planning Required" 'DOC Filter applied
i = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2))
       If Cells(i, 50) = "DOC Planning Required" Then
        
        Cells(i, 7).Copy
        Worksheets("DOC Fairshare").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("DOC Fairshare").Calculate
Worksheets("DOC Fairshare").Range("D11:U11").Copy
        Worksheets("Final Orders").Cells(i, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Debug.Print Cells(i, 2)
        End If
  '  Debug.Print Cells(i, 2)
    i = i + 1
    
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want accomplishing. So, you firstly filter "Final Orders" sheet and the filtering works correctly. Then, you try iterating between the filtered/visible cells of the AX:AX column and copy the value from G:G (the same row), if the iterated cell value is "DOC Planning Required", in Sheets("DOC Fairshare").Range("A3"). Calculate and then you need copying "D11:U11" starting from same cell of G:G where from you copied the trigger. Did you try running the code line by line? Until where it  works as you need? Is it a matter of no recalculation? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say anything... I asume that my understanding should be correct. The code also assumes that on the second row there are not headers. If they exist, the line `Set rngDocPl = ws.Range("AX2:AX1561")...` should be adapted to `Set rngDocPl = ws.Range("AX3:AX1561")...`.

Please, try the next code. It will stop after each iteration and shows in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G` being in VBE) the value in G:G before calculations and after. **Is it what you need**? I cannot imagine what formulas you have in `Worksheets("DOC Fairshare")` and I cannot test anything:

```
Sub DOCFairshare()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDoc As Worksheet, rngDocPl As Range, cel As Range

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final Orders") 'Setting worksheet in variable
  Set wsDoc = Worksheets("DOC Fairshare")     'is this sheet in the same workbook?
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False   'Removing all filters
    ws.Range("$A$2:$EL$1561").AutoFilter field:=50, Criteria1:= _
                                 "DOC Planning Required" 'DOC Filter applied
    On Error Resume Next
      Set rngDocPl = ws.Range("AX2:AX1561").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngDocPl Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No any visible cells in AX:AX column": Exit Sub

 For Each cel In rngDocPl.cells
    With wsDoc
         Debug.Print "before, on row " & cel.row, cel.Offset(0, -43).value     'the cell in G:G before calculations
        .Range("A3").value = cel.Offset(0, -43).value 'copy the value from G to "A3"
        .Calculate
        cel.Offset(0, -43).Resize(1, 19).value = .Range("D11:U11").value 'copy back the calculated range
        Debug.Print "after, on row " & cel.row, cel.Offset(0, -43).value: Stop   'the cell in G:G after calculations
    End With
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think something is wrong in for loop. I need to copy visible cell in column B in Final Orders sheet to cell A3 in DOC Fairshare sheet. Right now it is copying cell in column G instead. which is wrong

Comment: @Roha Ashfaq  Do you understand what `Cells(i, 7)` from your code means? Where in your code did you try copying something in "B:B"? Why don't you firstly answer my clarification question? Looking to your code I could not understand something else than I assumed. So, answer my question and I will adapt the code according to what I will be able to understand. If I will not clearly understand, I will ask another question and you should answer it/them. I do not like wasting my time...

Comment: @Roha Ashfaq If you want copying the 11th row, try changing `cel.Offset(0, -43).Resize(1, 19).value = ...` with `cel.Offset(0, -48).Resize(1, 19).value = ...`. And send some feedback...

Comment: @Roha Ashfaq Still alive?

Comment: I changed the code according to your last comment and it worked, sorry for not responding earlier, I was rebooting laptop

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to look at  and use *SpecialCells* method in VBA help. I think it is very  usefull.

In your case using like this example.

```
Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("C1")
```

It copies only visible cells to C1 from range A1-A10. I think more elegant then make loop and check if cell is visible and then copy which I used to do.

Comment: Im using the Cell(i,2) method because in that loop I need to manipulate both column 2 and column 7 cells, If I use the above method I will not be able to perform calculation on column 7 cells corresponding to column 2 cells

Comment: You can do what you want by e.g. `Set rng =  Range("$A$2:$EL$1561").Columns(50).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and then using a `For Each c In rng.Cells....Next c` to loop over that range.  Cells on each row can be accessed via `c.EntireRow` for example

Comment: `Dim rng As Range
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row      
Set rng = Range("B3:B" & LastRow)

     Dim cl As Range
    
    For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Debug.Print cl
        cl.Copy
        
    Worksheets("DOC Fairshare").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("DOC Fairshare").Calculate
Worksheets("DOC Fairshare").Range("D11:U11").Copy
 Worksheets("Final Orders").c1.Offset(0, 6).Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                
    
    Next cl

End Sub`

Comment: You didn´t specify what is wrong .... In Your comment You have typo if it is the case.  should be cl.offset(0,6) not c1.offset. I made, based on your code, simple test and it worked for me.